# Bash command to find files who have the same name but not the same extension

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I want to find files that do not co-exist with another file extention” i.e. all the .c files that don’t have a corresponding .o file. 
I tried `find $HOME \( -name '*.c' ! -a -name '*.o' \)` but it does work.

Comment: Judging from your example, do you actually mean “I want to find files that do not co-exist with another file extention” i.e. all the .c files that don’t have a corresponding .o file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. Find names of all files
2. Strip trailing extension, if any (assuming dot is only used before extension)
3. Sort to group duplicates
4. List only duplicates

The remaining lines list files that occur with different extensions

```
 find yourdirectory -type f | sed 's#\..*##' | sort | uniq -d
```

If you are only interested in extensions `.c` and `.o`, then confine the `find` accordingly.

```
find yourdirectory -type f -name '*.c' -or -name '*.o' | sed 's#\..*##' | sort | uniq -d
```

---

As it turns out, you actually wanted to know (and that should have been your question in the very beginning): "How to find .c files that have no .o file"

```
find yourdir -name '*.c' | sed 's#..$##' | sort > c-files
find yourdir -name '*.o' | sed 's#..$##' | sort > o-files
diff c-files o-files | grep '^<'
```

The final grep will filter lines that are only in the *left* files (c-files)

Comment: Unfortunately I only have files with multiple dots

Comment: then the sed has to be a bit more complicated:`sed 's#\.[^.]*$##'`
which means: replace (a dot, all but a dot, endofline) by nothing.

Comment: and if I want ".c" files that do not have a matching ".o" (sorry I did not ask the question correctly)